# Can this total length and curvature preserving transformation, from a closed planar curve to another curve, conserve also closure?

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

Related to this question, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380565/can-differential-geometry-aid-in-comparing-the-close-contour-integrals-of-fz , I am now seeking advice about how to best approach the following, somewhat more general, Differential Geometry problem involving closed planar curves:

- start from a closed planar curve $\gamma_1$ (regular, but not necessarily simple), described through its Whewell equation $\varphi(s)$ (i.e.: the tangent vector as a function of arc-length $s$).
- Transform $ \gamma_1 \, \rightarrow \, \gamma_2 \;\;$ through the tranformation: $\; \varphi (s) \, \rightarrow \, \varphi (s) + \theta(s) \;$.
- Whereby $\theta(s) $ monotonically increases from $\, \theta(0)=0 \,$ up to $\pi$ (though never crossing it over to values $>\pi$) to then monotonically come back to $\, \theta(L)=0 \,$ ($\, L \,$ representing the curve total length),
- No additional properties are specified for $\theta(s)$ .

It is straightforward to observe how the total curvature of $\gamma_2$ is conserved identical to the total curvature of $\gamma_1$ (as the rotation $\theta(s)$ always folds back to $0$ without ever having crossed over to values $>\pi$). Moreover, by definition also the total length is conserved.

I am asking myself whether it is true that such a transformation cannot possibly result in $\gamma_2$ also being a closed curve.

Heuristically, we might expect such a transformation to "open up" the originally closed curved $\gamma_1$ so that the resulting curve $\gamma_2$ would instead be an open curve. However, such kind of intuitions are often misleading, and I am hence searching for ways to more rigorously approach such kind of problems. Are there some already known Differential Geometry theorems which may help me in a rigorous study of this problem ? Or perhaps help in identifying candidate additional restrictions on $\theta(s)$ that would make it true ?

Advice on text books addressing this sort of problems is also welcome.

Comment: Take a look at our [mathjax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about subscripts, so that you have $\gamma_1$ instead of $\gamma1$.

Comment: If your problem is simply to prove that this transformation does **not** always result in a closed curve then all you need to do is to construct a single counterexample. Would that answer your question? If not, can you be more explicit about what you are asking?

Comment: subscript fixed, thanks for the tip. In fact my question relates to whether it never results in a closed curve, or to what other conditions are needed to guarantee that $\gamma_2$ cannot be closed, if they can possibly exist.

Comment: edited also in order to make the scope of the question more explicit, as suggested by Lee.

Comment: The next issue is that your third bullet is confusingly stated: I don't know what "increases up to asymptotic $\pi$" means. Is this what you mean? Namely that $\theta : [0,L] \to [0,\pi]$ is a continuous function such that $\theta(0)=\theta(L)=0$, and there exist $c \in (0,L)$ such that $\theta : [0,c] \to [0,\pi]$ is strictly increasing and surjective, and $\theta : [c,L] \to [0,\pi]$ is strictly decreasing and surjective.

Comment: Indeed, your translation into a more rigorous description is correct. I would only replace $[0,\pi]$ with $[0,\pi)$, which is what I was trying to informally convey by "increases up to asymptotic $\pi$", in the sense that $\theta$ might get arbitrarily close to $\pi$, though never actually reaching it.

Comment: That's exactly what worried me most about your formulation. There is no possibility that $\theta$ gets arbitrary close to $\pi$ without reaching it. That would violate the [Extreme Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), which says that a continuous real valued function on a closed interval has a maximum. So, your continuous function $\theta : [0,L] \to [0,\pi] \subset \mathbb R$ has a maximum value, which is either equal to $\pi$ or less then $\pi$.

Comment: Good point, I had missed this subtlety. My aim with that "increases up to asymptotic π" was to make it clear that $\theta(s)$ never crosses it over to values greater than $\pi$. Thanks to you observation I am now realizing that that was to hasty, and not strictly necessary for the main scope of my question. I will now consequentially edit my  question.